# Find user count accessing MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I have one MSMQ name privateQ1.I have given permission/access 10 id on local network. Is there any way to identify the particular message placed on queue by whom(user),similarly which user/process picked up the message from this queue.I want to identify the number of registered user listening to this MSMQ at a particular time.

Any help appreciated.

Avanish

Answer (score 1):

The SID of the sending account is stored in the message header.
So it's a property you can query programmatically.

You should be able to use Windows auditing on the queue to determine what processes/accounts access the queue. You need to enable an audit policy on the machine and then set the security properties for the access types you wish to audit.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: Is there any class in c# by which we can determine...? i am newbee in this field could you help me.